# How do I fix WiX warning: Component 'X' has both per-user and per-machine data with an HKCU Registry KeyPath

Tags: wix

I'm trying to maintain some Wix code, and am getting the following warning:

```
warning LGHT1076 : ICE57: Component 'FILE_MY_ASSOCIATION' has both per-user and per-machine data with an HKCU Registry KeyPath.
```

From the following code:

```
<Component Id="FILE_MY_ASSOCIATION" Guid="E1DF42A5-BD00-4a80-9BE5-B66A3EF0576E" Win64="$(var.Variables_Win64)">
  <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MyComany\MyProduct">
    <RegistryValue Value="" Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
  </RegistryKey>
  <ProgId Icon="FILE_MY_FILETYPE_ICON" Id="MY_FILE_EXTENSION" Description="My Product File" >
    <Extension Id="myext" Advertise="no" >
      <Verb Id="Open" Argument="&quot;%1&quot;" TargetFile="MYUI_EXE_FILE"/>
    </Extension>
  </ProgId>
</Component>
```

I'm having trouble working out what's wrong or if this is a warning I really need to worry about.

- Do I need to worry about and fix this warning? Could the code as it is currently cause problems in some circumstances?
- Also, I'm wondering, why does the registry key use HKCU instead of HKLM. If I change it to HKLM. the warning goes away, but does this affect the behaviour of the installer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The warning is saying that you are writing both user-specific data and system-wide data in the same component.  Your registry entry is writing to `HKCU` which will always write to a user-specific piece of the registry.  `ProgId`, on the other hand, writes registry entries to [HKCR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724475%28VS.85%29.aspx) which could write to either `HKLM` or `HKCU`.  If it does write to `HKLM` that is a system-wide registry space, your single component is writing to both a user specific registry hive and a system registry hive which is against the rules laid out in the [ICE warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368994%28VS.85%29.aspx) you got.

Comment: Interestring. So ProgId can go to per user or per machine hives. I wonder, does the presence of RegistryKey entry do anything to force the ProgId to go to HKCU instead of HKLM?

Comment: No, the [KHCR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724475%28VS.85%29.aspx) link explains the rules for when it goes to HKCU vs HKLM.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the compiler is alerting you to behavior which may not be what you want: if you register a file association for the user only, other users will not see that association.  That's an unusual behavior for an application.   So, it depends on your requirements:  do you want the app registered to handle all documents of that type for all users, or only the installing user?

Comment: Hmm. I probably want the app registered to handle all documents of that type for all users. Can you tell me what it will do as it is written currently?

Comment: Maybe you're saying the fragment as it is will register the file association only for the installing user.