# understanding keyPath issue for both perUser and perMachine

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

WIX 3.10

I read answers here on the site but none seem to satisfy my curiosity to understand the difference between perUser vs PerMachine when it comes to `KeyPath`

here is the perUser part

```
<Package Compressed="yes"
              InstallerVersion="200"
             Manufacturer="company name"
             Description="tool name"
             Comments="comments"
             Platform="x64"
             InstallScope="perUser"/>
```

so my directory hierarchy is (perUser)

```
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir" >
         <Directory Id="AppDataFolder" Name="AppDataFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Concept Attribute Editor" />
         </Directory>
         <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
            <Directory Id="ConceptAttributeEditorShortcut"
                       Name="Concept Attribute Editor">
            </Directory>
         </Directory>
         <Directory Id="DesktopFolder">
         </Directory>
      </Directory>
```

and when build I am getting error says that a component has both per-user and per-machine data with a per-machine keyPath. How would I tell that a keypath is for a machine or a user ? isn't it enough to be a child of a DirRef that is a perUser specific?

example:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
         <Component Id="cmp9E3CD94933B0EB4D8E119985E636EFAA" Guid="F8703A26-2332-4658-BF4C-5FD9B03D2CAB" KeyPath="yes" Win64="yes">
            <RegistryKey ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" Key="CLSID\{5A9D8C50-28CA-44E7-BC56-D77949F016E8}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45E7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" Root="HKCU" />
         </Component>
      </DirectoryRef>
```

now, when i remove the keyPath it still complaints about keyPath conflict. Any thoughts or explanations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key path isn't "for" per machine or per user, a key path is just a key path. Also, you get the error when you remove the key path because (I believe) WiX makes you a default key path.

The general issue with these user/machine ICE tests is that they are static and don't know whether the install will ultimately be per user or per machine, so you get the warning even if it won't apply. There are usually ways to avoid the warnings.

[There is a good answer here, so if the answer by heavyd helps, give him the credit.
[How do I fix WiX warning: Component 'X' has both per-user and per-machine data with an HKCU Registry KeyPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016522/how-do-i-fix-wix-warning-component-x-has-both-per-user-and-per-machine-data-w)
]

The general problem is with resources that are installed for a particular user. It's also related to repair (and updates) because the key path defines the resource that will be used for repair, checked for updates by version checking, but that isn't too relevant here.

If you install a registry item or a file to a user profile location in a per machine install then the resource isn't installed for any other users. Perhaps use of a shortcut will prompt a repair, but there's no guarantee of that (unless you designed explicitly for installation on demand), which means the installed product is potentially broken for other users - you have per user data in a per machine install and some users don't have everything because there are missing files or registry entries. Since the ICE tests don't know that a per user install will actually happen you get the error for HKCU. The situation potentially becomes  worse if you patch or upgrade because the result could be unpatched files. That's why ICE57 documentation says:

"Mixing per-user and per-machine data in the same component could result in only partial installation of the component for some users in a multi-user environment"

and you get the multi-user environment if you do a per machine install. (There may be some terminal services types of setup that are affected, but I have not checked that.)

In your case, it's possible that changing the root to HKMU would fix the warning, because HKMU means HKCU in per user and HKCR in per machine. The ICE test shouldn't complain about that.

Comment: things make sense once you mentioned HKMU. to my surprise I haven't seen this root value before. I am good now, accepted as answer.